# I can't find my "WIndows 8" Partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, dell

My girlfriend had her Dell Pre-Installed with Windows Vista when she bought it,then she upgraded it to Windows 7 and then 8.Since she wanted an Operating System which is fast and powerful i suggested Ubuntu for her.She runs a Dell Inspiron 1420 with 2 gigs of ram and an Nvdia 8400M GS,though the laptop is a bit old,it does her things like a dream.
So,I have used a Flash Drive(8 Gigs) to install Ubuntu 13.04 on her system and used "Overwrite the Windows 8 OS".Then afterwards when I logged in I can't find any of her files which was on her WIndows 8 installation.

Anyone know a work around with this?!

Answer (score 3):

Since you choose "Overwrite the Windows 8 OS" I think her files are gone. Since "Overwrite" means "Overwrite". It has installed Ubuntu over her Win8 OS.

If you wanted a "Dual boot" you should choose "Install along side Windows 8" or "Something else"..

Afraid her data is lost...